# Как вставить почтовый шаблон в другой почтовый шаблон?

Tags: битрикс

Есть шаблон с именем NAME1 (общая часть для данных) и шаблон NAME2 (использующий данные). Как внутрь NAME2 запихнуть NAME1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак - это нельзя сделать, но можно написать обработку события отправки почты и там уже поменять на то что вам понадобиться.

Comment: Я уже понял. Вставка генерилась непосредственно в коде.